# Unrecognized Field error in deserialization with Jackson

Tags: java, json, deserialization

I'm having problems deserializing JSON into my POJO object.

This is my JSON

```
{"userID":"346","userMemID":"10","userFirstName":"FIRSTNAME","userLastName":"LASTNAME","userSkillLevel":"7","userProviderID":"098"}
```

And here is my Class

```
public class Drivers {

private String userID = "";
private String userMemID = "";
private String userFirstName = "";
private String userLastName = "";
private String userSkillLevel = "";
private String userProviderID = "";


public String getUserID() {
    return userID;
}

public void setUserID(String userID) {
    this.userID = userID;
}

public String getUserMemID() {
    return userMemID;
}

public void setUserMemID(String userMemID) {
    this.userMemID = userMemID;
}

public String getUserFirstName() {
    return userFirstName;
}

public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
    this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
}

public String getUserLastName() {
    return userLastName;
}

public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
    this.userLastName = userLastName;
}

public String getUserSkillLevel() {
    return userSkillLevel;
}

public void setUserSkillLevel(String userSkillLevel) {
    this.userSkillLevel = userSkillLevel;
}

public String getUserProviderID() {
    return userProviderID;
}

public void setUserProviderID(String userProviderID) {
    this.userProviderID = userProviderID;
}
```

}

This is the function that recieves the JSON.

```
@POST
@Path("/save")
@Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
public ResourceResponse saveDrivers(Drivers entities) {
    ResourceResponse resourceResponse = new ResourceResponse();
    driversBean.saveDrivers(entities);
    resourceResponse.setReturnCode(ResourceResponse.GOOD);
    return resourceResponse;
}
```

This is the code that sends the JSON  I don't think this is the problem though because the JSON string is formatted correctly

```
saveDrivers: function(criteria) {
        var mySettings = {
                type: "POST",
                url: "../resources/drivers/save",
                data: ko.toJSON($ata.drivers.model),
                cache: false,
                dataType: "json",
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                success: function(data) {
                    if(data.returnCode === "001") {
                        alert("Save successful!");
                    }
                    else { 
                        alert("saveDrivers FAILED!");
                    }
                },
                error: function() { alert("saveDrivers FAILED!"); }
            };
        $.ajax(mySettings); 
    }
```

The error I receive says Unrecognized field "userID" not marked as ignorable.

Please help I am at my wits end.

Comment: Just updated with the code that receives the JSON

Comment: Can you share the code that sends the json as well?

Comment: I just did but I don't think the function sending it is the problem because the JSON string is formatted correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try mapping your class like so?  I have a hunch that your PropertyNamingStrategy is not correctly reflecting the JSON property name.

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.annotation.JsonProperty;

public class Drivers {

    @JsonProperty("userID");
    private String userID = "";

    @JsonProperty("userMemID");
    private String userMemID = "";

    @JsonProperty("userFirstName");
    private String userFirstName = "";

    @JsonProperty("userLastName");
    private String userLastName = "";

    @JsonProperty("userSkillLevel");
    private String userSkillLevel = "";

    @JsonProperty("userProviderID");
    private String userProviderID = "";

    public String getUserID() {
        return userID;
    }

    public void setUserID(String userID) {
        this.userID = userID;
    }

    public String getUserMemID() {
        return userMemID;
    }

    public void setUserMemID(String userMemID) {
        this.userMemID = userMemID;
    }

    public String getUserFirstName() {
        return userFirstName;
    }

    public void setUserFirstName(String userFirstName) {
        this.userFirstName = userFirstName;
    }

    public String getUserLastName() {
        return userLastName;
    }

    public void setUserLastName(String userLastName) {
        this.userLastName = userLastName;
    }

    public String getUserSkillLevel() {
        return userSkillLevel;
    }

    public void setUserSkillLevel(String userSkillLevel) {
        this.userSkillLevel = userSkillLevel;
    }

    public String getUserProviderID() {
        return userProviderID;
    }

    public void setUserProviderID(String userProviderID) {
        this.userProviderID = userProviderID;
    }

}
```

Comment: Yup that fixed it! I only had to do it for my userID attribute so I'm not exactly sure why that was the only one that was unrecognized but either way its working now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 0):

If you have the access of JSON string then you can convert it into Java object using [`ObjectMapper`](http://jackson.codehaus.org/1.7.3/javadoc/org/codehaus/jackson/map/ObjectMapper.html)

```
String jsonString = "{\"userID\":\"346\",\"userMemID\":\"10\",\"userFirstName\":\"FIRSTNAME\",\"userLastName\":\"LASTNAME\",\"userSkillLevel\":\"7\",\"userProviderID\":\"098\"}";
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
Drivers driver = mapper.readValue(jsonString, Drivers.class);
System.out.println(driver.getUserID()); // 346
```

Comment: Have you tried my sample code as standalone program?

Comment: No, but I do not know how to set up another standalone program with these dependencies.  This was set up for me...

Comment: do you know how to make a standalone program that contains `public static void main(String[] a){...}`

Comment: Yeah but I don't know how to import objectmapper into that project.